# mod_rewrite works for URLs with en, es but not zh-tw and zh-cn?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

My sites are in 4 languages and they are accessed with the following pattern:

```
http://example/index.php?lang=en
http://example/index.php?lang=es
http://example/index.php?lang=zh-tw
http://example/index.php?lang=zh-cn
```

I'm using the following **mod_rewrite** rule in my **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?)/(.*) $3?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

So typing http://example/en/index.php and http://example/es/index.php efectively redirects me to http://example/index.php?lang=en and http://example/index.php?lang=es respectively. But that doesn't work with  http://example/index.php?lang=zh-tw and http://example/index.php?lang=zh-cn

It just says: `The requested document was not found on this server.`

It is something to do with the hyphen (zh-tw and zh-cn)?

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `[A-Z]` with `[a-z]`.

Comment: Yes thanks I just figured out that! So can I just delete the [a-z] at the front?

Comment: @janoChen No, keep it, it is still neccesary, that catches the part before the hyphen.